# Oreo requestFocus does not work

Tags: android, android-edittext

When i trying to request focus of `EditText` - it doesnot work **(On Android >=8)**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/name"
    style="@style/TextInput.Text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/login_name"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true" />
```

To call request I am using `nameInput.apply { requestFocus() }`

Comment: Were you able to get it to work I have same problem. After name.requestFocus I will have to touch the screen anywhere before it get focus.

Answer (score -1):

you can set `focus` in `xml` as in

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/name"
    style="@style/TextInput.Text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/login_name"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true">
  <requestFocus/>
</EditText>
```